# How can I simplify this SQL Schema?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-schema

In this SQL diagram, I have two medication tables. One medication table is for Mastitis disease treatment and the other medication table is for the treatment of other diseases. The fields are similar except for the foreign keys. Any advice on how to refactor the schema to remove redundancies?
[image: sql schema]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Comment: It all depends on the `SELECTs` you will use.

Comment: Is "mastitis" not a form of "problem"?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for marking it as a duplicate question and pointing me to the right path.